# Another JSON Data in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, json, uipickerview

I've taken a look a few other examples but I still can't seem to figure out why my `pickerView` stays empty.

**JSON File**

```
{
"artstyle": [
             {
             "id": 1001,
             "name": "Plain",
             "prefix": "plain"
             },
             {
             "id": 1002,
             "name": "Brushed",
             "prefix": "brushed"
             },
             {
             "id": 1003,
             "name": "Swirly",
             "prefix": "swirly"
             }
             ]}
```

**.h**

```
@interface FlipScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property NSArray *artArray;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@interface FlipScrollViewController ()

@end

@implementation FlipScrollViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Getting the file path from the local bundle.
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"art" ofType:@"json"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

}
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;


    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //self.artArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    //NSLog(@"get: %@", _artArray);


   //NSArray* shapeguide = [json objectForKey:(@"artstyle")];
    // this spits out the whole JSON file contents
    //NSLog(@"Guide: %@", shapeguide);

    //NSDictionary *art = [shapeguide objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"Guide: %@", guide);
    // Displays the "name" value in the Label text

    //name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[guide objectForKey:@"name"]];

    //self.artArray = [art objectForKey:@"name"];

  _artArray = [json objectForKey:(@"name")];
    //NSLog(@"Guide: %@", _artArray);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [_artArray count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [_artArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

/*
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    //to do
    return [self.artArray count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    return [[self.artArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"name"];

}
 */

@end
```

I know I have set the delegates correctly and I know the JSON data is being spit out correctly. I've put NSLogs in at various place to check. You can see from parts of the .m that I have tried a bunch of different ways to get this thing working.

I've spent a few days on this now and I'm running out of hair to pull. Plus it seems bloated so any tips to clean it up would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should not just throw your .h and .m files. This is not a fix-my-homework site. Describe what you've done and only add the relevant code. Also, it is unclear what didn't work. Add a screenshot of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;


NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"Guide: %@", json);

_artArray = [json objectForKey:@"artstyle"];

[<picker> reloadAllComponents];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
NSDictionary *dict = [_artArray objectAtIndex:row];
NSLog(@"dict: %@", dict);
return [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: This worked well. Although I'm not exactly sure why. I get the reloadAllComponents part. it seems you made a dictionary from my array to get strings? The strings then populate the picker? If you wouldn't mind a short explanation that'd be great. Thanks again regardless.

Comment: once the array loaded we need to reload the picker controller to populate the contents from the array. Since you are loading the content from the file, before array loads from the file content the picker may try to load the content from the array. At this time the array may not have any data in it. So it will not show any content in the picker. Thats why, each and every time once the array is loaded with the content we need to reload the picker components. Try to keep breakpoint in the picker delegates and run the app. you may know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the json data as *ASYNCHRONOUS* .

So hopefully, you forgot to call the `reloadAllComponents`, once it gets done.

For Ex:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
// ........All your stuff
[pickerView reloadAllComponents] ;
}
```